# Resetting the Google Map position after clicking off an Infowindow

Tags: google-maps

I have a google map which includes infowindows when clicking on markers in the map. When clicking on a marker, the infowindow for that marker opens up and repositions the map.

The client would like the map location to reset to the original position and close the infowindow when clicking anywhere in the map that is OFF the infowindow.

The code I have so far is below. Thank you!!

```
  <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [
  ['<div class="leftalign"><?php echo $addr1; ?></div> <div class="rightalign"><img src="<?php echo $addr1_image; ?>" alt="General Image"></div>', 38.4505064,-122.7268983, 4],
  ['<div class="leftalign"><?php echo $addr2; ?></div> <div class="rightalign"><img src="<?php echo $addr2_image; ?>" alt="General Image"></div>', 38.377517, -121.946924, 5],
  ['<div class="leftalign"><?php echo $addr3; ?></div> <div class="rightalign"><img src="<?php echo $addr3_image; ?>" alt="General Image"></div>', 38.574165, -121.559870, 3],
  ['<div class="leftalign"><?php echo $addr4; ?></div> <div class="rightalign"><img src="<?php echo $addr4_image; ?>" alt="General Image"></div>', 38.794887, -121.217039, 2],
  ['<div class="leftalign"><?php echo $addr5; ?></div> <div class="rightalign"><img src="<?php echo $addr5_image; ?>" alt="General Image"></div>', 38.670913, -121.160873, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('custommaploading'), {
  zoom: 9,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.477191,-121.5400331),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  scrollwheel: false,
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement that functionality?  What issues did you encounter?

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks for the reply. I Added an event listener to close the infowindow when clicking on the map but I can't seem to reposition the map. Here is what I have: google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    infowindow.close();

    map.setCenter(center);

    });

Comment: Please address comments by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out.

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out. Here is the answer in case anyone else needs it:

```
//Latitude and Longitude position
var myLatlng = {lat: 38.477191, lng: -121.5400331};

//On map click
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
//Close all info windows
infowindow.close();
//Center the map
map.setCenter(myLatlng);
});
```